# VueJS build deployment history

Tags: git, vue.js, deployment

I'm using VueJS 2 in my project and I realized that my build deployment is bad.

This is my script to deploy my VueJS build on github :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
cd ../..
VUE_APP_ENV=demo vue-cli-service build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

git push -f git@github.com:MyRepo/my-project.git master:my-project-demo-deployment

cd -
rm -rf dist/
```

After that, I go to my remote server and I get the new build with this command:
`git pull origin --rebase`
I'm using this command because I don't have git history so I can't pull. Each time the build is deleted because I delete the `dist/` folder.

But this way to deploy my build on remote server is not very good because I can't easily come back to a previous commit because I have one and only commit each time I build/push.

I want to know if there is a solution to deploy all my different builds on the github to do normally `git pull` my new build on the remote server. I have to edit my script but I don't know what is the best solution. Maybe I have to create another repo to store all my build commits ? I don't know. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why do you not use a platform for the whole process of deployment + rollback + tracking ? (Netlify, Vercel)

Comment: You mean that is the server who build the app ?

Comment: Platforms like Netlify will track a specific github repo (where you will casually push your latest code), then it will fetch it on their own servers, run a `yarn build`, and expose it on one of their URLs or a custom domain (your own). And it's free, especially for a basic usage.

Comment: Oh ok so with Netlify I can choose any commit in my branch and make a new build + deploy with this commit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a side project that I started few weeks ago, pretty much nothing done yet (just configuration). But you can see that:

- I do have access to a domain name out of the box: `https://cyrielle-design.netlify.app`
- it is plugged to my private Github repo:
  `github.com/kissu/free-cyrielle-front`
- I have 3 deploys: initial one + `add netlify gitignore` + `build: add new fancy package + config`

[image]

If I click on one of those builds, I can have access to a few settings, one of which is a "Deploy site", aka a rollback to a previous build.

[image]

So yeah, it's not an answer to your question directly but I felt that it was nice to speak about a platform that will help your heavily on your deployment process.

---

I'm not sponsored or whatever, but I can give some of my opinions on it.

There are plugins that allow you to use some backend features easily (lambda functions + forms), you have true analytics, split testing, auth, it's managing the whole cache invalidation for you, and a lot of great things. And it will probably stay in the free tier until you really start to have some serious company business with a lot of traffic IMO.

Vercel is another great alternative. I know that you can also host on Firebase or even Digitalocean and Cloudflare now. But I do use Netlify and it is probably the most simple solution for frontend apps as of right now (pretty much the Heroku equivalent).

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. As you say I think I need to use a deployment tool. So I have to give write access on my server to Netlify to make it works ?

Comment: Netlify is a platform that will handle everything for you. You push the code, they do all the lifting for you. So, the only thing that you need to grant access for, are private repos (if you want to deploy something private).

Comment: Oh ok I see the build is hosted on their server, right ? So it doesn't work if I have my own server ?

Comment: You can make it work on your own server if you do it by hand (aka with no tools). But Netlify will host it for you, that way you will not have the need to be careful with the Apache config, nor the DNS stuff, nor the package updates, nor the possible network issues, nor any accident (like fire hazard) or DDOS etc etc... What is your actual server ? It's a VPS with an Ubuntu on it on Digitalocean or alike? Also, you're probably paying a small amount of fee for your server, so why paying if you can simply host your frontend app for free ? Netlify is a no-brainer for me as you can see, lol.

Comment: Actually my app is hosted on google cloud server with docker / nginx next to the backend

Comment: If you really want to bring it next to your backend, you will need to do it by hand I guess. But if you can achieve to deploy your whole docker properly, I guess that you're better than me on devops and that you will find out a solution pretty quickly. :) At the end of the day, the frontend doesn't need to be on a docker because it far less complex and since it's static (SPA in your case), it can be hosted more easily than a whole cluster of micro-services. So, you could have your backend in Docker and your frontend on Netlify. Depends of your need and your confidence into your infrastructure.

Comment: I have a question about the pricing. Netlify free plan will host my website even if I pay nothing with the free plan ?

Comment: Yep, this is exact ! Never paid a dime to Netlify myself. https://www.netlify.com/pricing/

Comment: Cool right ? At the end, it's pure static front-end files, so no heavy backend server running, hence why it is free. So yeah, it removes the pain of hosting and infrastructure. :3